# Why is does my solution give the same value for sum(n in order) as for sum(n in order:(n-1) in order)

Tags: cplex

I'm working on a consolidation model in which you can see which orders are consolidated and which aren't based on its hypothetical volume. However, my code does not work for every combination of orders... Here is my .mod file:

```
//GENERAL PARAMETERS
 int nr_trucks = ...;
 
    //Sets
 {int} origin_terminal = ...;
 {int} gateway_terminal = ...;
 {int} destination_terminal = ...;
 
 {int} order = ...;
 {int} cons_truck = ...;
 
 int capacity_cons_truck[cons_truck] = ...;
 
    //Ranges
 range truck = 1..nr_trucks;
 
 //ORDER PARAMETERS
 int volume[order] = ...;
 int non_cons_truck[order] = ...;
 
 //NETWORK PARAMETERS
 int fixed_cost_OTG[origin_terminal, gateway_terminal] = ...;
 int fixed_cost_GTD[gateway_terminal, destination_terminal] = ...;
 
 //DECISION VARIABLE
 dvar int+ x_OTG[origin_terminal, gateway_terminal, truck, order] in 0..1;
 dvar int+ x_GTD1[gateway_terminal, destination_terminal, truck, order] in 0..1;
 dvar int+ x_GTD2[gateway_terminal, destination_terminal, cons_truck, order] in 0..1;
 
 //OUTPUT VARIABLES
 dvar int+ y[gateway_terminal, truck, cons_truck, order] in 0..1;
 dvar float exp_fixed_cost_1[origin_terminal, gateway_terminal, truck, order];
 dvar float exp_fixed_cost_2[gateway_terminal, destination_terminal, truck, order];
 dvar float+ exp_fixed_cost_3[gateway_terminal, destination_terminal, cons_truck];
 dvar int+ A[cons_truck];
 dvar int+ B[cons_truck];

 //PARAMETERS TO WRITE OUTPUT TO EXCEL
 tuple tuple_x
 {
   int terminal;
   int terminal2;
   int truck;
   int order;
   int value;
 };
 
 tuple tuple_y
 {
   int terminal;
   int truck;
   int cons_truck;
   int order;
   int value;
 };
 
 tuple tuple_cost_1_2
 {
   int terminal;
   int terminal2;
   int truck;
   int order;
   float value;
 };
 
  tuple tuple_cost_3
 {
   int terminal;
   int terminal2;
   int truck;
   float value;
 };
 
 
 //MODEL
 minimize sum(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_1[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n]
        + sum(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_2[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n]
        + sum(h in cons_truck) exp_fixed_cost_3[1,1,h];
        
 subject to
 {
  //FLOW CONSTRAINTS
  forall(n in order) x_OTG[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] == 1; //(2)
  
  forall(n in order) x_OTG[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] ==  x_GTD1[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] + sum(h in cons_truck) x_GTD2[1,1,h,n]; //(3)
  
  //forall(n in order, h in cons_truck) x_OTG[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] + x_GTD2[1,1,h,n] <= 1 + y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n]; //(4a) minder strikt?
  forall(h in cons_truck, n in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n] == x_GTD2[1,1,h,n]; //(4a)
  forall(h in cons_truck) sum(n in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n]*volume[n] <= capacity_cons_truck[h]; //(4b) 
  forall(h in cons_truck) sum(n in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n] != 1; //(4c) only more than 2 order can be put on a consolidated truck
  
  forall(n in order) sum(h in cons_truck) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n] <= 1; //(5a) order cannot be split over multiple trucks
  forall(n in order) sum(h in cons_truck) x_GTD2[1,1,h,n] <= 1; //(5b)
  
  forall(h in cons_truck) sum(n in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n] == A[h]; //number of consolidated orders in truck h
  forall(h in cons_truck) sum(n in order: (n-1) in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n] == B[h]; //all but one consolidated orders in h
    
  
  //EXPECTED FIXED COSTS
  forall(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_1[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] >= fixed_cost_OTG[1,1]*x_OTG[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n]; //(6a)
  forall(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_2[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] >= fixed_cost_GTD[1,1]*x_GTD1[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n]; //(6b)
  forall(h in cons_truck) exp_fixed_cost_3[1,1,h] >= sum(n in order) x_GTD2[1,1,h,n]*fixed_cost_GTD[1,1] - sum(n in order: (n-1) in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n]*fixed_cost_GTD[1,1] ; //(6c) 
    
  forall(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_1[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] >= 0;
  forall(n in order) exp_fixed_cost_2[1,1,non_cons_truck[n],n] >= 0;
  forall(n in order, h in cons_truck) exp_fixed_cost_3[1,1,h] >= 0;
 }
 
 //OUTPUT TO EXCEL
 {tuple_x} output_x_OTG = {<i,j,g,n,x_OTG[i,j,g,n]> | i in origin_terminal, j in gateway_terminal, g in truck, n in order};
 {tuple_x} output_xGTD1 = {<i,j,g,n,x_GTD1[i,j,g,n]> | i in gateway_terminal, j in destination_terminal, g in truck, n in order};
 {tuple_x} output_xGTD2 = {<i,j,h,n,x_GTD2[i,j,h,n]> | i in gateway_terminal, j in destination_terminal, h in cons_truck, n in order};
 
 {tuple_y} output_y = {<i,g,h,n,y[i,g,h,n]> | i in gateway_terminal, g in truck, h in cons_truck, n in order};
 
 {tuple_cost_1_2} output_exp_fixed_cost_1 = {<i,j,g,n,exp_fixed_cost_1[i,j,g,n]> | i in origin_terminal, j in gateway_terminal, g in truck, n in order};
 {tuple_cost_1_2} output_exp_fixed_cost_2 = {<i,j,g,n,exp_fixed_cost_2[i,j,g,n]> | i in gateway_terminal, j in destination_terminal, g in truck, n in order};
 {tuple_cost_3} output_exp_fixed_cost_3 = {<i,j,h,exp_fixed_cost_3[i,j,h]> | i in gateway_terminal, j in destination_terminal, h in cons_truck};
```

Here is my .dat file:

```
SheetConnection excel("One_to_one_no_leadtime.xlsx");

 //GENERAL PARAMETERS
 //nr_orders = 3;
 nr_trucks = 3;
 
 origin_terminal = {1};
 gateway_terminal = {1};
 destination_terminal = {1};
 
 order = {1,2,3};
 cons_truck = {1,2,3};
 
 //ORDER PARAMETERS
 volume = [40,70,20];
 non_cons_truck = [1,2,3];
 capacity_cons_truck = [100,100,100];
 
 //NETWORK PARAMETERS
 fixed_cost_OTG = [[75]];
 fixed_cost_GTD = [[75]];
 
 //OUTPUT WEGSCHRIJVEN
 output_x_OTG to SheetWrite(excel,"'output'!A3:E1100");
 output_xGTD1 to SheetWrite(excel,"'output'!G3:K1100");
 output_xGTD2 to SheetWrite(excel,"'output'!M3:Q1200");
 
 output_y to SheetWrite(excel,"'output'!S3:W1000");
 
 output_exp_fixed_cost_1 to SheetWrite(excel,"'cost'!A3:E200");
 output_exp_fixed_cost_2 to SheetWrite(excel,"'cost'!G3:K200");
 output_exp_fixed_cost_3 to SheetWrite(excel,"'cost'!M3:P200");
```

As you can see, the model says that A[h] and B[h] are the same when the volume = [40,70,20] in the .dat file. Why is sum(n in order) equal to sum(n in order: (n-1) in order)? This problem does not emerge when the volume = [40,40,80], then the model works perfectly. I really don't know what's going on... I know that it is an elaborate model, but please let me know if someone could help! Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your optimal solution 300, A and B are the same but their formula are different.

If you add a new constraint

```
A[1]!=B[1];
```

then you get a new solution with objective 375

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much! It indeed works. However, if I expand my model to 5 orders for example with volume = [40,40,40,40,20], then the model does not run if I add `A[1] != B[1]; and A[2] != B[2];`. Could you find an explanation for this?

Comment: Even if A and B are computed through different formula, in some cases A and B get same values in order to get a feasible solution.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the swift response! I see that this could be an explanation, but there is no relaxation if I run the model. The consolidation happens correctly, but it won't calculate the costs as it should i.e. line `(6c)` in my model states that the fixed costs can only be taken once since the truck needs to ship everything 1x regardless of how many orders that it is transporting. Do you see where I can make an adjustment in the model in order that it calculates the fixed costs one time in case of consolidation? Thanks a lot for your help until now! Kind regards

Comment: Hi Alex, I think that I found the mistake in line `forall(h in cons_truck) exp_fixed_cost_3[1,1,h] >= sum(n in order) x_GTD2[1,1,h,n]*fixed_cost_GTD[1,1] - sum(n in order: (n-1) in order) y[1,non_cons_truck[n],h,n]*fixed_cost_GTD[1,1] ; //(6c)`, the model will leave out the last order. However, it can only leave out 1 **consolidated** order. Do you know how I can make this clear? Thank you in advance! Kind regards